# Statistical variance of strata in carbon estimation areas

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics

How do I determine statistical variance within project areas?

I need a process to identify an area with similar raster data (ie soil moisture or soc) and elevation. What I want to do is determine the best way to stratify a project so that we reduce the variation and make project areas more homogeneous. Australia has many raster datasets on soil  which can be found https://data.csiro.au/search/keyword?q=soil%20attributes

What I have tried so far is a simple split with lines to divide areas based on elevation. I do not have any experience with statistical variance.

Comment: Hi @Sarah, could you share with us what you have tried so far, just edit your question.